# Sybase: Error accessing tables using Delphi and Firedac

Tags: delphi, sybase, firedac

Using DELPHI 10.3 I tried to access tables in a sybase db with Firedac. I can connect but a statement like `select * from sometable` results in an error-message:

> "[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Spalte 'object_id' nicht gefunden." (Column 'object_id not found).

Connecting works:

```
  FDConnection1.Params.Clear;
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('DriverID=ASA');
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('OSAuth=No');
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('Compress=No');
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('ODBCAdvanced=AutoStop=Yes;Delphi=Yes;CommLinks=tcpip(host='+ed_IP.Text+')');
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('Server='+ed_Server.Text);
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('Database='+ed_Database.Text);
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('User_Name='+ed_User.Text);
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('Password='+ed_Password.Text);
  FDConnection1.Params.Add('MetaDefSchema=dba');
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;
  IF FDConnection1.Connected THEN
    ConnectionButton.Caption := 'CONNECTED'
  ELSE
    ConnectionButton.Caption := 'ERROR';
```

Components used: TFDConnection, TFDPhysASADriverLink, TFDGUIxAsyncExecuteDialog.
Thx in advance for any hint...

Comment: Try to exclude fiMeta from FetchOptions.Items. Does it help ? If yes, then are your server and ODBC driver have compatible versions ?

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I think to change profession... ;-)